# jquery prev() doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have this html code:

```
<body>
<div class="CodeRay">
<div class="code"><pre><span class="no">   1</span> require <span class="s"><span class="dl">'</span><span class="k">yaml</span><span class="dl">'</span></span>
<span class="no">   2</span> require <span class="s"><span class="dl">'</span><span class="k">set</span><span class="dl">'</span></span>
<span class="no">   3</span> 
<span class="no">   4</span> <span class="r">module</span> <span class="cl">ActiveRecord</span> <span class="c">#:nodoc:</span>
<span class="no">   5</span>   <span class="c"># Generic Active Record exception class.</span>
<span class="no">   6</span>   <span class="r">class</span> <span class="cl">ActiveRecordError</span> &lt; <span class="co">StandardError</span>
<span class="no">   7</span>   <span class="r">end</span>
<span class="no">   8</span>
...
</body>
```

For this html code I have javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('span').not('.no,.c,.r,.pc').click(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    var element = target.prev('.no');
    element.effect('highlight', {}, 'slow');
});
```

The problem is `prev()` returns the same object as before, can't find `.no` element. It doesn't searching through the predecessors of elements in DOM tree. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/shaneblake/bRRmA/

I've updated the jsfiddle with the following line of code to address your comments:

`$(this).prevAll('.no:first').effect('highlight', {}, 'slow');`

Comment: Hm, doesn't work either, I've changed to alert http://jsfiddle.net/AWJ2K/, could you check again, thanks

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do...  When I click `yaml` it highlights the 1.  When I click `set` it highlights the 2.  What should it highlight?  Should something else be clickable?

Comment: You understood me in right way, but it doesn't work on my side.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work on ActiveRecord, ActiveRecordError and StandardError.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you selector `$('span').not('.no,.c,.r,.pc')` excludes all `.no` so its hardly surprising you're seeing nothing.

You could try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('span').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.is(".no,.c,.r,.pc"){
        $this.prev('.no').effect('highlight', {}, 'slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, you're better this `$(this)`. I've also refactored a bit above.